# Nested SQL select

Tags: sql

I have a single large SQL Table and I have the following query with returns some basic info:

```
SELECT 
     CustomerID AS "Customer Name" 
    ,COUNT(ID) AS "Total Emails"
FROM EmailDatas WHERE Expired = 0
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

## Result

```
Customer Name         Total Emails
A                        1000
B                        9200
C                        11400
```

What I am trying to do is get a count of emails for todays date returned in the same query, something like:

## Result

```
Customer Name         Total Emails          Emails Today
A                        1000                   34
B                        9200                   7
C                        11400                  54
```

I can amend the original query to return the info:

```
SELECT 
     CustomerID AS "Customer Name" 
    ,COUNT(ID) AS "Total Emails"
FROM EmailDatas WHERE Expired = 0 and starttime > getdate()
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

What I need is basically to have these 2 queries combined.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: what is    `starttime`    here???

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Tag dbms used. (You are using product specific functionality.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  Something like this:

```
SELECT CustomerID AS "Customer Name", 
       COUNT(ID) AS "Total Emails",
       SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(starttime as date) = CAST(getdate() as date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Today's"
FROM EmailDatas
WHERE Expired = 0 
GROUP BY CustomerID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this also.

```
select t1.CustomerName,t1.TotalEmails,
case when t2.EmailsToday is null then 0 
else t2.EmailsToday end as EmailsToday 
    from (SELECT 
         CustomerID AS CustomerName
        ,COUNT(ID) AS TotalEmails
        FROM EmailDatas WHERE Expired = 0
        GROUP BY CustomerID) t1 
    left join
        (SELECT 
         CustomerID AS CustomerName 
        ,COUNT(ID) AS EmailsToday
        FROM EmailDatas WHERE Expired = 0 and starttime > getdate()
        GROUP BY CustomerID) t2
    on t1.CustomerName=t2.CustomerName
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT
t1.CustomerID AS [Customer Name],
t1.[Total Emails],
t2.[Emails Today]
FROM
(SELECT 
CustomerID
,COUNT(ID) AS [Total Emails]
FROM EmailDatas WHERE Expired = 0
GROUP BY CustomerID) AS t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT 
CustomerID
,COUNT(ID) AS [Emails Today]
FROM EmailDatas WHERE Expired = 0 and starttime > getdate()
GROUP BY CustomerID) AS t2 
ON t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID
```